# How do i set up tabbing for <div> elements that are siblings instead of parent/child

Tags: javascript, html, accessibility, wai-aria

I have an info box that is split in to 3 columns with categories in the left col, sub categories in the middle, and the info in the right col. Im trying to configure the tabbing order so that so that it goes through each cat/subcat/info. Unfortunately cat/subcat/info laid out as sibling elements instead of parent/child.

Is there anyway that do this easily? Also, is there a js method i could use to set the currently focused tab element? (something like .focus() on the element)

```
<div>
  <div class="active">item 1</div>
  <div>item 2</div>
  <div>item 3</div>
  <div>item 4</div>
</div>

<div>
  <div class="active">item 1 sub 1</div>
  <div>item 1 sub 2</div>
  <div>item 1 sub 3</div>
  <div>item 1 sub 4</div>
</div>

<div>
  <div>item 1 sub 1 content 1</div>
  <div>item 1 sub 1 content 2</div>
  <div>item 1 sub 1 content 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are trying to fix it the wrong way, semantic HTML is very important in accessibility so if the relationship is left to right you need to go back to how you generate the page and change the markup from column based to row based I am afraid. We could do it with a load of `aria` but it would be hard to maintain. I know that doesn't answer your question but doing this with JS only fixes tab order, it won't fix relationships that are important for screen reader users. Yes `element.focus()` sets focus in JS (but you need `tabindex="-1"` on an element that is not usually focusable).